# AIT/HbbTV testing for Sony, Panasonic

Tags: sony, hbbtv

With Panasonic and Sony KDL series, we cover some compatibility issues with AIT application, loading transparent page with a small redbutton overlay appears with black instead of transparent background.

Furthermore, some devices stop broadcast stream's audio playback.

Javascript error logging doesn't catch error, warning or notice with these devices. It's loading the script but seems to fail silently with rendering the page - or expects another setting than Samsung, LG and other Sony devices support.

Is there a vmware/virtualbox or another more reliable emulation for hbbtv/ait testing? In Opera and Samsung emulators, and on Samsung + LG devices, there is no bug observed and js error tracking working as expected. However, with Sony KDL series and Panasonic, additional input for testing practice is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a TV emulator by Opera from http://www.operasoftware.com/products/tv/tv-developer-tools but it will only cover the TV sets based on Opera (Presto) like Sony. The most other devices like Samsung and LG are based on Webkit with custom HbbTV extensions. You will need several devices to get a good test coverage.

If you only use a transparent page for the red button without a video/broadcast object, you shouldn't have any effect on the audio or video playback.